# How to click on the ahref link using selenium webdriver 2.25 - java?

Tags: java, webdriver

I am unable to click on the Opportunity link
                                                                                           Action| Opportunity Name  | Account Name | Stage | Close Date | Opportunity Owner

```
<th scope="row" class=" dataCell ">
  <a href="/006b00000029ay9?srPos=0&amp;srKp=006" data-seclke="Opportunity" data-seclkh="bf4b3627c01dbc9e32ca3a945ddbe3ec" data-seclki="006b00000029ay9" data-seclkp="/006b00000029ay9" data-seclkr="1" onclick="searchResultClick.click(this)" onmousedown="searchResultClick.click(this)">Test Opp1</a>
```

I have added (-) hyphen in front of the tags to paste the HTML exact code what I am getting. I need to click on the ahref.
Kindly advise me what should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Test Opp1")).click();
```